# Git: Do SHAs for commits shown in git log differ from those in a PR?

Tags: git

I've created and checked out a feature branch from master.  I then make 5 commits.  When I push my branch to the remote repo and open a PR, it shows those 5 commits but with different SHAs than what I see in `git log`.

My understanding was that each commit has a unique SHA so I was expecting them to be the same.  Is my understanding incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: This can't be happening, so the only explanation I can think of is either you are not looking the right branch locally, or not looking at the same branch on the remote.

Comment: It's worth noting that the difference in commit IDs (SHA sums) will never be caused by Git, which relies on commit IDs being identical across all systems that share those commits. But, it *can* happen because of human error, like rebasing locally forgetting to push, or because of malicious reasons, like an attacker injecting code into your repository. Both cases are cause for concern, the commit IDs in your pull request *must* be the same as your local commits before you can confidently perform a merge on either end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding was that each commit has a unique SHA

Yes, that's right.

> so I was expecting [the hash IDs in the pull request] to be the same.

Either they *are* the same, or the pull request is for *different commits*.

The latter is always possible: anyone (or anything) can copy any existing commit by extracting it and then changing some data and re-committing.  The resulting commits might even have the same *snapshots*, but different metadata, and therefore be different—i.e., have different hash IDs.

If the hash ID matches, the commit is 100% identical.  If not, *something* is different, but the hash ID alone won't tell you what.  Use `git fetch` to retrieve the commit—note that you can fetch pull requests—and then inspect the commit locally to see what is different.  Note that retrieving a pull request with `git fetch` requires that you know the web-host's *name* for the pull request.  For GitHub, this is straightforward: a pull request made *to* a repository whose URL is *U* and whose pull request number is *N* is available under the name `refs/pull/N/head` at URL *U*.